# Chef Test-Kitchen platform with GUI

Tags: ubuntu, user-interface, chef-infra

With Test-Kitchen for Chef, is there any way in which I can test a platform which has a GUI installed?

For example, I wish to provision Sublime Text onto an ubuntu node. I do this by adding the webupd8 ppa (http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/sublime-text-2-ubuntu-ppa.html), and then install the sublime-text package.

This fails because the Ubuntu-14.04 platform without a GUI doesn't have /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/ (this is the error I receive).

I would like to test this on a platform which has a GUI. Is there any way to specify my own vagrant box to use for the testing in kitchen? The documentation of this project seems to be incomplete at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some documentation regarding the kitchen.yml file at http://docs.getchef.com/config_yml_kitchen.html#provisioner-specific-settings

Basically, the solution to what I was looking for is that you can set the box as an attribute of one of the platforms under test:

```
platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-14.04
    driver:
      box: janihur/ubuntu-1404-desktop
```

In this case, the box is one that was found on vagrantcloud.com